# Psycopg2 Throwing Syntax error over dynamically generated SQL

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

So i have the following snippet where i am trying to generated a Dynamic SQL for insert, following is my payload that is passed as payload.

```
data = {"id": "123", "name": "dev", "description": "This is the dev Env","created_by":"me","updated_by": "me","table_name": table_name}
```

I am getting the following error for above mentioned payload.

```
LINE 1: ...updated_by, table_name) VALUES (123, dev, This is the dev En...
```

My Implementation:

```
class DMLRelationalDB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass;

    def insert_sql(self, params):
        """

        :param params:
        :return:
        """
        converted_dict = self.__convert_params_to_columns_and_placeholders(params)
        print(converted_dict)
        column_names = ", ".join(converted_dict['columns'])
        placeholders = ", ".join(converted_dict['values'])
        table_name = params["table_name"]
        statement = f"""INSERT INTO {table_name} ({column_names}) VALUES ({placeholders})"""
        print(statement)
        return statement

    def __convert_params_to_columns_and_placeholders(self, items_dict):
        """

        :param items_dict:
        :return:
        """
        columns = []
        values = []
        for key, value in items_dict.items():
            columns.append(key)
            values.append(value)
        return {"columns": columns, "values": values}
```

Comment: Aren't the `"` missing on your strings?

Comment: Yes, that is the case, but i dont know why its not being handled by the code

Comment: Try with `placeholders = ", ".join([f'"{val}"' for val in converted_dict['values']])`

Comment: Wont this convert every thing to string?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a problem for SQL. It will check the types of your columns and save the data correctly

Comment: You could even go further and do something like `placeholders = ", ".join([f'$str${val}$str$' for val in converted_dict['values']])` for postgres. This way you can be sure that the quotation marks will not colide with data that you have inserted

Comment: So if there is a Datetime value? it will be converted properly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217403/discussion-between-borisdonchev-and-noobie-php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to pass string values to your postgres DB without quoting them first. Personally I would quote all the data that will enter the database, just to make sure that it is handled correctly.

What you can do is the following:

```
placeholders = ", ".join([f'"{val}"' for val in converted_dict['values']])
```

If you have different types of data like datetimes for example the string representation will be put inside the f-string, so it would be safe.

If you have strings that contain double quotation marks you could use "dollar-quoting" to be on the safe side:

```
placeholders = ", ".join([f'$${val}$$' for val in converted_dict['values']])
```

If you think that there is a possibility that some string of yours would have two dollars after another, then put some string between the two-dollars to make it abolutely safe:

```
placeholders = ", ".join([f'$str${val}$str$' for val in converted_dict['values']])
```

The downside to this is that you increase the amount of data that is transfered and if you have lots of information, it will decrease the performance.